# How to query relation through few tables to get things from the the middle of this relation?

Tags: python, django, database, django-orm

Imagine, that I have a relation:

Auto <-> doors <-> Window

and I want to find all cars with open windows. I can do that with:

```
Auto.filter(door__window__status__in=['open', 'almost open'])
```

But how can I find with single query, which windows caused that particular car was returned in a query?

I need this information, to display something like this?

- Red Ford (**front left window** is opened)
- Green Mustang (**front right window** is opened)

Is situation differ much if I will have always m2m relations between all 4 tables?

Comment: I don't see why you would want m2m relationships here at all. A window can only belong to one door, and a door can only belong to one car; these are both FKs. Perhaps you need a less made-up example?

Comment: I have different relation in my real database.... A<->B<->C<->D.... and between each table I have m2m relation. I need to query table A according to data in table D, but I also need to display information from table C, which cause that there is a relation between A and D. I have assumed, that It would be easier to understand, If I will use example from the question, even I my real database has a little bit more complex scheme.

Comment: please share your models, so we understand better the strcuture and the relation.

Answer (score -1):

I've considered this models:

```
from django.db import models


class A(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class B(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    a = models.ManyToManyField(A)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name        

class C(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    b = models.ManyToManyField(B)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name                

class D(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    C = models.ManyToManyField(C)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Now run the following query:

```
results = A.objects.filter(b__c__d__in=['d1','d2']).all().values('name','b__name','b__c__name','b__c__d__name')
```

Will give you desire results